# How many different substrings are in a string?

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

I need to design an algorithm in O (n) that given a string t of length n, calculate the number of different substrings of t.

Comment: and what is your approach?

Comment: Formula is: **N!/(E0! ... Em!)** where E0 ... Em are the counts of the m distinct characters in the string. Seems pretty simple to take it from there in O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build a suffix automaton for the input string.
2. Find the sum of `maxLength[v] - maxLength[suffixLink[v]] for all states v`, where `maxLength[v]` is the longest path from the root to the `v` state and `suffixLink[v]` is a suffix link for this state.

Constructing a suffix automaton in a linear time is a well-known problem. The second part is just a simple traversal. Thus, the total time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly that I need.

For if it helps someone else leave the link where I found the algorithm.
[english google's translate](https://translate.google.es/translate?hl=es&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fe-maxx.ru%2Falgo%2Fsuffix_automata)
[original in russian](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_automata)